# How to combine the commands "find" and "nano"

Tags: bash, find, nano

How can I combine the "find" command with the "nano" command?

For example,

```
find . -name "helloworld.py" | nano
```

How to open that file (first out of several lets say) after it is found using "nano" (without using a function but a single line of chained commands)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To edit the first file only,

```
find . -name helloworld.py -exec nano {} \; -quit
```

This looks for files named `helloworld.py`, and for each such file found, runs `nano /path/to/helloworld.py`, and then quits (which means that only the first file will be processed).

To edit all the matching files,

```
find . -name helloworld.py -exec nano {} +
```

This runs `nano` with as many files as will fit on the command line. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to close each file in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `find`, you can also enable `globstar` option.

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
nano **/helloworld.py
```

Disable `globstar` with `shopt -u globstar`.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care for the whitespace:

```
nano $(find . -name helloworld.py)
```

Comment: This will fail for any path containing spaces and is very bad practice.

Comment: @pLumo True. Added the correction.